# Firemonkey Scrambles graphics on laptop

Tags: windows, graphics, driver, firemonkey

I have an application that plots quarter degree blocks on a map using Timage stacked on each other.  I then add records by drawing them on a separate layer.

The problem I have is that Firemonkey (or Windows) scrambles the graphics, but only on some computers, and I think all the affected computers are laptops.  See the following links for screenshots:

[image: http://i724.photobucket.com/albums/ww241/BushSnake/GraphicsError_1.jpg]
[image]

The correct image should look like this:
[image]

On laptops this scrambling may take 3 repaints of the layers, but sometimes (on exactly the same code) it happens after 1 or two times.  While it is inconsistent in exactly how many repaints it takes, it is guaranteed to happen after no more than 3 paints.

So I have come to the conclusion that it must be a Graphics driver issue.  I have a NVidia Geforce 950M on my laptop (Asus NJ551 with Windows 10), but if I understand the code correctly I am using the Windows Direct2D acceleration so the Nvidia drivers shouldn't affect things?

I set the following flag by default:   GlobalUseDX10Software := true;  //Use DirectX to generate graphics, but this does not seem to make any difference as it still scrambles even when set to false.

I would prefer the Windows acceleration as my users may not all have a graphics card installed. A friend using a HP laptop (not sure of the model but running Windows 8) does not experience the issue, yet another friend with a brand new HP laptop (low spec but with Windows 10) is also experiencing the issue.

Can someone please help out here?  I am out of ideas, and I'm not even sure what to Google.  Is it Windows 10, is it the Graphics driver, etc? Is there a way I can force my laptop to use the Graphics card for testing?  While this will not help other users without proper graphics cards, it may help isolate the issue.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: I forgot to add, I am using Delphi XE8

Answer (score 0):

From the EDN forum, I got the a number of other Graphics related global variables to set.  The one that sorted out the issue is:
GlobalUseDXSoftware := True;

It now makes sense, as the issue started happening after moving to XE8 from XE5, and the GlobalUseDX10Software flag is now deprecated